# how to use map with a defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x

We want to use the `map` function that uses a defined function (`mutation_detector`), this function has two arguments: `DNA` (string) and `mutated_DNA` (list of strings).
For some reason it doesn't work.

```
DNA = "ATGCTGATGCTCGCCTCGATGATAGCTCGCTCGATAGACTCGCTAAAGCTCGTAGCTGATCGCCTAGATGCCTAGATCCGTAGC"

dna_letters=("CATG")
def random_mutation(dna):
    """this function takes a dna seq and chooses a random location and random letter and changes it"""
    if len(dna)>1 and set(dna).issubset(dna_letters):
        mutation=random.choice(dna_letters)  
        location=random.randint(0,(len(dna)))
        mut=list(dna)
        mut[location]=mutation
        dna_with_random_mutation="".join(mut)
        return dna_with_random_mutation 
    else:
        return ("Wrong input")

mutated_DNA=list(map(random_mutation,[DNA]*100)) 


def mutation_detector(dna1,dna2):
    """this function recive 2 dna sequencesin the same length and returns the first index that have a diffence between them"""
    if type(dna1)==str and type(dna2)==str and len(dna1)==len(dna2) and set(dna1).issubset(dna_letters) and set(dna2).issubset(dna_letters):
        list_dna1=list(dna1)
        list_dna2=list(dna2)
        unique=list(zip(list_dna1,list_dna2))
        for i in unique:
            if i[0]!=i[1]:
                return unique.index(i)
            elif list_dna1==list_dna2:
                return (-1)
    else:
        return "Wrong input"

mutation_indices=(list(map(mutation_detector,DNA,[mutated_DNA])))
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What are you trying to do here! Please provide expected output and input for us to avoid guesswork :) @DanaRimini

Answer (score 1):

First of all, list indexes go from `0` to `len(lst)-1`, so to avoid out of range errors, change

```
location=random.randint(0,(len(dna)))
```

to

```
location=random.randint(0,len(dna)-1)
```

Second, here's how to use `map` with a function of one or more arguments:

```
mutation_indices = list(map(lambda x: mutation_detector(x,DNA), mutated_DNA))
```

This applies the `mutation_detector` function to each element in `mutated_DNA`, with `DNA` as the second argument to `mutation_detector`.

After these changes, `print(mutation_indices)` outputs:

```
[-1, -1, 52, -1, 24, 64, 3, 52, 56, 33, 72, 16, 52, 66, -1, 68, 67, -1, 51, 29, 31, 64, -1, 28, 74, 49, 23, 28, 35, 21, 40, -1, 54, -1, -1, 11, 65, 15, 77, 56, 26,62, -1, -1, 53, 21, 56, 40, 67, 36, 49, 13, 67, 69, 24, 41, -1, 41, 32, 44, -1, 72, 49, 5, 56, 2, 40, 2, 34, 46, 47, 16, 30, 11, -1, 78, -1, 32, 50, 13, 37, -1, 60,30, 7, 12, 81, 71, 64, 62, 16, 7, 45, 35, 79, 29, 43, 6, 51, 37]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original trial of using `map` doesn't work at all. If you'd want to use `map` you'd need to use it together with a `lambda` to pass the constant `DNA` argument to the `mutation_detector` function.

Instead of doing that you should use a list comprehension, it will make the code clearer and faster:

So replace this:

```
mutation_indices=(list(map(mutation_detector,DNA,[mutated_DNA])))
```

With this:

```
mutation_indices = [mutation_detector(DNA, mutated) for mutated in mutated_DNA]
```

---

You also need to change this line in your `random_mutation` function to avoid an `IndexError`:

```
location=random.randint(0,(len(dna)))
```

To:

```
location = random.randint(0, len(dna) - 1)
```

---

Here's a cleaned up version of your code with these fixes applied:

```
import random


def random_mutation(dna):
    """this function takes a dna seq and chooses a random location and random letter and changes it"""
    if len(dna) > 1 and set(dna).issubset(dna_letters):
        mutation = random.choice(dna_letters)
        location = random.randint(0, len(dna) - 1)
        mut = list(dna)
        mut[location] = mutation
        dna_with_random_mutation = "".join(mut)
        return dna_with_random_mutation
    else:
        return ("Wrong input")


def mutation_detector(dna1, dna2):
    """this function recive 2 dna sequencesin the same length and returns the first index that have a diffence between them"""
    if type(dna1) == str and type(dna2) == str and len(dna1) == len(
            dna2) and set(dna1).issubset(dna_letters) and set(dna2).issubset(
                dna_letters):
        list_dna1 = list(dna1)
        list_dna2 = list(dna2)
        unique = list(zip(list_dna1, list_dna2))
        for i in unique:
            if i[0] != i[1]:
                return unique.index(i)
            elif list_dna1 == list_dna2:
                return (-1)
    else:
        return "Wrong input"


DNA = "ATGCTGATGCTCGCCTCGATGATAGCTCGCTCGATAGACTCGCTAAAGCTCGTAGCTGATCGCCTAGATGCCTAGATCCGTAGC"
dna_letters = ("CATG")

mutated_DNA = list(map(random_mutation, [DNA] * 100))
mutation_indices = [mutation_detector(DNA, mutated) for mutated in mutated_DNA]

print(mutation_indices)
```

> Example output:
>
> ```
> [54, 78, 22, 47, 42, 65, 56, 4, 53, 79, -1, 2, 5, 17, -1, 69, -1, 43, -1, 66, 71, -1, 23, 79, 79, -1, 73, 64, -1, 8, 52, 58, -1, 8, 78, -1, 11, 12, 32, 4, 61, -1, -1, 12, -1, 80, -1, 35, 47, 17, 45, 1, -1, 43, 0, 41, 32, 66, 63, -1, 26, 43, 76, 65, 33, 19, 46, -1, -1, 10, 56, 45, 76, 66, 43, 19, -1, 14, -1, 77, 30, 79, 45, 81, 49, 42, -1, 27, 7, -1, 68, 81, -1, 44, 13,37, -1, 59, -1, 38]
> ```

Comment: Well `map(foo, bar)` is the same as [foo(i) for i in bar)]` right @ruohola?

Comment: Also the `mutation_detector` returns `Wrong Input` which I don't think makes sense for a function to be used in a map!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh But in this case OP needs the additional `DNA` argument also.

Comment: @glhr The original trial for the `map` usage will not work, it has quite a lot of problems.

Comment: Also your change throws the same exception the OP's code throws `line 12, in random_mutation mut[location]=mutation IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yes, but fixing that wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: Well actually the OP isn't very clear on what the problem is and just says `the function doesn't work` which I assume is the exception part!